# How to set image size in carousel slider flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter. I am using carousel slider package to show image. I want to set my image size. Now I faced the problem with my vertical image have been crop and show part center only.  Here is my code:

```
final List<String> imgList = [
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205408450-add114ad53fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=368f45b0888aeb0b7b08e3a1084d3ede&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=94a1e718d89ca60a6337a6008341ca50&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
];

final List<Widget> imageSliders = imgList.map((item) => Container(
  child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(item, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000.0),],
      )),),
)).toList();


class CarouselWithIndicatorDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _CarouselWithIndicatorState();
  }
}

class _CarouselWithIndicatorState extends State<CarouselWithIndicatorDemo> {
  int _current = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Carousel with indicator demo')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          CarouselSlider(
            items: imageSliders,
            options: CarouselOptions(
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              aspectRatio: 2.0,
              onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                setState(() {
                  _current = index;
                });}), ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: imgList.map((url) {
              int index = imgList.indexOf(url);
              return Container(
                width: 8.0,height: 8.0,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,color: _current == index ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9): Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                ), );
            }).toList(),
          ),  ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This function can help you while scrolling left to right carousel images

```
Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: parentHeight * .025),
          child: CarouselSlider(
            height: parentHeight * .45,
            enlargeCenterPage: true,
            reverse: false,
            autoPlay: true,
            autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 4),
            autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
            autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            enableInfiniteScroll: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            onPageChanged: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _current = index;
              });
            },
            items: imageTextList.map((data) {
              return Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Wrap(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 8.0, /*vertical: 10.0 */
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                        ),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                          child: Image(
                            image: new AssetImage(data.imageUrl),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      getNewTextLayout(data, parentHeight, parentWidth),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have error about The method 'getNewTextLayout' isn't defined for the class '_CarouselWithIndicatorState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getNewTextLayout'.